# Retrieving gorilla registry of all currently saved sessions

Tags: go, gorilla

I created my backend using `gorilla/sessions` to store some informations about active users. Now I want to create some code monitoring the active users, so I need to retrieve all the saved session, thus retrieving their `Session.Values` map. Is there an easy way to do that without saving redundant data? Thanks.

Comment: Why using Values map is overhead for you, in case when you have already had them? Could you provide more details?

Comment: Normally `session, err := store.Get(httpRequest, "name")` is used to get the user session. What I thought is that in this case I could save the http requests of the users in a global variable (a map or a slice). If I'm not mistaken this is needed internally to get the cookie session id. I think this is an ugly workaround, I hope there is a better way...

Comment: Ok then. But if you're working with sessions, you have to collect them in some storage. If the answer is "no", why do you need them? Probably the best solution is getting sessions from such storage. If you don't have it, you should implement it based on map or on something else.

Comment: Yes. The question is if there's a way to simply access that storage, if not, then I'm going to use a database so that I can query it easily, this would be a lot of work tough, I need a very simple thing.

Comment: Got it. As I know, ```gorilla/sessions``` can't do what you want.